# Массив заполняется не полностью c++

Tags: c++

Нужно нарисовать пирамиду, содержащую n строк. Если n будет, например, 4, то пирамида должна выглядеть следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но у меня получается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#define n 4

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int row, col, left, right, top, bottom, num, fixright, arr[n][2*n-1];
    left=0;
    right=2*n-2;
    top=0;
    bottom=n-1;
    num=1;
    for(row=0; row<n; row++){
        for(col=0; col<=2*n-2; col++){
            arr[row][col]=0;
        }
    }
    do{
        fixright=right;
        for(col=left; col<=right; col++){
            arr[bottom][col]=num;
            num++;
        }

        for(row=bottom-1; row>=top; row--){
            right--;
            arr[row][right]=num;
            num++;
        }

        for(row=top+1; row<=bottom-1; row++){
            right--;
            arr[row][right]=num;
            num++;
        }

        top++; bottom--; left+=2; right=fixright-2; 
    } while(left>right); 

    for(row=0; row<n; row++){
        for(col=0; col<=2*n-2; col++){
            if (arr[row][col]!=0)
                cout<<arr[row][col]<<"\t";
            else
                cout<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: А что за манера (не первый раз вижу) постить C++ код в формате JS?

Comment: просто stack ругался, что код плохо отформатирован и пришлось постить в js:)

Comment: А почему просто не запустить дебагер с точками входа на каждую итерацию и посмотреть, как меняются значения, и где не присваиваются значения?)

Answer (score 0):

надо было вместо `while(left>right);` написать `while(bottom>top)`